# Replace style with JS to multiple clases

Tags: javascript

How can i do this code work with multiple classes?

```
$("td.field_358").each(function() {
    var td = document.getElementsByClassName('field_358');
    for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        if (td[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Yes') !== -1) {
            td[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f7fef7';
        } else if (td[i].innerHTML.indexOf('No') !== -1) {
            td[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fbe8ea';
        }
    }  
})
```

Actually i'm repeating the code for diferents classes, just replacing the class... field_358, field_123...etc.
Its possible to do something more handy like:

```
$("td.field_358", "td.field_359", "td.field_360").each(function() {
  var td = document.getElementsByClassName('field_358', 'field_359', 'field_360');
});
```

I'm a JS Noob...

Comment: two ways off the top my my head; 1. feed the value `field_123`or whatever as a parameter to a wrapping function, or 2. do a `split()` on the `.` and use the second half to populate your `td` var.  I will say though, that, not knowing the specifics it seems there is a better way to do whatever you are doing.  also: I tried to edit and add `jQuery` tag because it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put all the css-classes you're interested in in an array and iterate over that. For each iteration you execute the code you've already got:

```
['field_358', 'field_359', 'field_360'].forEach(function (cssClass) {

  var td = document.getElementsByClassName(cssClass);

  for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    if (td[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Yes') !== -1) {
       td[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f7fef7';
    } else if (td[i].innerHTML.indexOf('No') !== -1) {
      td[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fbe8ea';
    }
  }
});
```

A working example may be found at https://jsfiddle.net/9sba06r4/3

Side note: You don't need jQuery for this task, just a more-or-less up-to-date browser.

Sources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: it didnt work... ['field_336', 'field_330', 'field_796', 'field_359', 'field_358'].forEach(function (cssClass) {

  var td = document.getElementsByClassName(cssClass);

  for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    if (td[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Sí') !== -1) {
       td[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f7fef7';
    } else if (td[i].innerHTML.indexOf('No') !== -1) {
      td[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fbe8ea';
    }
  }
});

Comment: i just solve it with this: var colors = ['field_336', 'field_330', 'field_796', 'field_359', 'field_358'];

colors.forEach(function (cssClass) {

  var td = document.getElementsByClassName(cssClass);

  for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    if (td[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Sí') !== -1) {
       td[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f7fef7';
    } else if (td[i].innerHTML.indexOf('No') !== -1) {
      td[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fbe8ea';
    }
  }
});

Comment: Well, then there's a problem with how/when you're executing it or other code interferes. The example you gave is working: http://jsfiddle.net/9sba06r4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable function that allows you to pass an array of numbers representing the ids you wish to target, and also allows you to pass in strings representing the colors you wish to use for highlighting.

You simply define your arguments to the function and call it.

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const yesColor = '#37fef7';
const noColor = '#fbe8ea';

highlightTds(ids, yesColor, noColor);

function highlightTds(ids, yesColor, noColor) {
 
  ids.map(id => {
    const tds = document.querySelectorAll(`.field_${id}`);
  
    for (const key of Object.keys(tds)) {
      if (tds[key].innerHTML.indexOf('Yes')) {
        tds[key].style.backgroundColor = yesColor;
      } else if (tds[key].innerHTML.indexOf('No')) {
        tds[key].style.backgroundColor = noColor;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="field_1">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field_2">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field_3">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field_4">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field_2">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field_1">No</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```